# Finding an element by value using the Firebase Javascript API

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Here is my code that adds new colors to the table, it works perfectly and the Firebase Dashboard shows that each color is added with a new id to the colors table:

```
// example pushColor('yellow') {
function pushColor(colorName) {

    var colorsRef = fireBaseRef.child("colors");
    colorsRef.push(colorName, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            alert("Color could not be saved." + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Before I add a new color, however, I want to make sure that the one I am adding doesn't already exist in the table. Here is my attempt so far:

```
function colorExists(colorName) {
    var colorsRef = fireBaseRef.child("colors");

    colorsRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
        if (exists) {
            alert(colorName + ' exists!');
        } else {
            alert(venueName + ' does not exist!');
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that when I submit my form, I get the following behavior:
First time checking for color "black" (with an empty table):

```
"black does not exist!"
```

I add black as a color.

Second time checking color "black":

```
"black exists!"
```

...so far, so good. But then if I submit color "purple" (not in the database) I get:

```
"purple exists!"
```

Anything I search for after inserting the first color returns "exists!"

I'm guessing that I am not understanding the way that the colorExists() method is working, can anyone point me in the right direction towards fixing this function so that it does what I want, or help me find the related documentation to find an entity by one of its values?

Answer (score 0):

Moments after posting this I figured it out... I needed to update my colorExists method to the following (code could use some cleanup but I hope everyone sees what I changed):

```
function colorExists(colorName) {
    var colorsRef = fireBaseRef.child("colors");

    colorsRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot !== null) {

           snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {

                // if the value matches the name we specified
                if (snapshot.val() === colorName) {

                    exists = true;
                    return;
                }
            });

            if (exists) {
                alert(venueName + ' exists!');
            } else {
                alert(venueName + ' does not exist!');
            }
        });
}
```